# FileNotFoundException with An Internal Error has Occurred while reading from a NAS

Tags: java

We've been getting a weird FileNotFoundException where we know the file is there, but Java is throws an FileNotFoundException (An Internal Error has occurred).  For some reason, when we try to create a FileInputStream to the file, we get the below exception.  To make it even more interesting, it is an intermittent issue.  Usually if we wait a while and rerun our job, it works.  Wondering if anyone has seen this before and can provide some insight.  Anyone encountered a file not found with a Thanks in advance.

Error:

```
2017-07-24 22:21:53,838 [processorExecutor-47041-3-] ERROR FileReaderController - error while reading file: \\<some path to a nas>\2017-07-24\r_i_t_2808732.rdb
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\<some path to a nas>\2017-07-24\r_i_t_2808732.rdb (An internal error occurred)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
```

Our process works by checking the files on the NAS first, before attempting to read each one via the above code.  So by the time it hits this section of the code, we know the file is there. Since we encounter this, we added more error logging code.  It seems that even though we are not able to open an inputstream, we are still able to get a file handle and query properties regarding the file.

Updated Code with Additional Error Logging code

```
private InputStream getInputStream(String path) throws IOException {
        final int retryAfter = 5;
        InputStream in = null;
            try {
            in = new FileInputStream(path);
    } catch( IOException e ) {
        logger.warn("Error creating FileInputStream from " + path + ". Checking file status.", e);
        checkFileStatus(path);

        // retry
        logger.info("Retrying in 5s");
        try {
        Thread.sleep(retryAfter * 1000);
        in = new FileInputStream(path);
        } catch( IOException ex ) {
        logger.error("Retry: Error creating FileInputStream from " + path + ".", ex);
        throw ex;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        String errorMsg = "Retry: Interrupted while waiting to retry creating FileInputStream from " + path + ".";
        logger.error(errorMsg, ex);
        throw new IOException(errorMsg, ex);
        }
        }
        return in;
}

private void checkFileStatus(String path) {
    File f = new File(path);        
    logger.info("File status:");
    logger.info("  exists:" + f.exists());
    logger.info("  isFile:" + f.isFile());
    logger.info("  isHidden:" + f.isHidden());
    logger.info("  canRead:" + f.canRead());
    logger.info("  length:" + f.length());
    logger.info("  lastModified:" + LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(f.lastModified()), ZoneId.systemDefault()));
}
```

additional logging output. it clearly indicates the file was there.  The retry attempt also fails.

```
2017-07-24 22:21:08,784 [processorExecutor-47041-3-] INFO  FileReaderController - File status:
2017-07-24 22:21:08,800 [processorExecutor-47041-3-] INFO  FileReaderController -   exists:true
2017-07-24 22:21:08,800 [processorExecutor-47041-3-] INFO  FileReaderController -   isFile:true
2017-07-24 22:21:08,800 [processorExecutor-47041-3-] INFO  FileReaderController -   isHidden:false
2017-07-24 22:21:08,800 [processorExecutor-47041-3-] INFO  FileReaderController -   canRead:true
2017-07-24 22:21:08,800 [processorExecutor-47041-3-] INFO  FileReaderController -   length:7460
2017-07-24 22:21:08,800 [processorExecutor-47041-3-] INFO  FileReaderController -   lastModified:2017-07-24T22:17:48.716
2017-07-24 22:21:08,800 [processorExecutor-47041-3-] INFO  FileReaderController - Retrying in 5s
```

Comment: Check if the file has been given the permission to read or write.

Comment: I would recommend to use `java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Path, OpenOption...)` to open an `InputStream`

Comment: update question.  if we wait and reprocess later, it usually works.  Further, don't think it is a permission issue since it would say access denied.